# Error "UNC paths are not supported - trying to run a batch file in a network directory

Tags: batch-file

The full error message is:

'\192.168.0.10\drive - 3TB\Libraries\Videos-3TB\movies'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
The network path was not found.

I'm just trying to save all file names into a text file by running the batch file from the parent folder in the network:

```
@echo off
tree /f /a > Listfile.txt
pause > nul
```

You experts will solve this in two seconds, if you would be so kind. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by running the file from a local directory and pointing to where it was located before when i got the error

```
@echo off

tree "\\192.168.0.10\Berry - 3TB\Libraries\Videos-3TB\movies" /f /a > Listfile.txt

pause > nul
```

Comment: If you simply want a list of files, you might consider `dir /b /a-d "\\192.168.0.10\Berry - 3TB\Libraries\Videos-3TB\movies" >Listfile.txt`

Comment: How do i remove the path info with that then?

Comment: Ah, if you really want just the file names, then you would need to run the commnd through FOR /F. Also, I forgot the `/S` option in my prior comment. Here is  the command that would print file names without path, (but then you don't know where the files reside) - `>Listfile.txt (for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /s /b /a-d "\\192.168.0.10\Berry - 3TB\Libraries\Videos-3TB\movies"') do echo %%~nxF)`

Comment: I see, that is very helpful, i know i'm not supposed to use the comment feature for this but, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you could also map a network drive

```
net use z: "\\192.168.0.10\drive - 3TB\Libraries\Videos-3TB\movies"
pushd z:
tree /f /a > Listfile.txt
```

Comment: This assumes z: has not already been claimed. A safer bet is to use `pushd "\\192.168.0.10\drive - 3TB\Libraries\Videos-3TB\movies"`, and then use `popd` at the end.

Answer (score -2):

Why you can't is because programs started in cmd with a network directory as current crash if the CMD is closed. You can do in some roundabout way, but as you see the correct way works best.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.6001]
Copyright (c) 2006 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

\\serenity\C$>
```

Comment: Huh? How can the CMD window close before the TREE command has completed? Obviously CMD is not closed, otherwise the OP could not see the error message. And what "correct way" are you referring to? You should provide more context to indicate you are referring to the OP's own answer.

Comment: Anyone can go and search the KB where the cause is quite clear. The answer has been at MS's web site for at least 20 years. Set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` and value name of `DisableUNCCheck` to a DWORD of `1`. In a shortcut to CMD set the Start In directory to a network path like `\\serenity\C$`. **If you start a program like SQL server and close the CMD window,you'll crash your server apps started from it.**